# What version of Matlab should I install to make dsearch() work?

Tags: matlab

I have a code in MATLAB that I need to run once to get some quick reference results. This code uses dsearch(), and I relized that this function has become deprecated and has been substituted by dsearchn(). I tried to follow some suggestions to make it work but I didn't succeed (it's my absolute first time with MATLAB) and I just need to run this code once to get some numbers. Which MATLAB versione should I install to make it work?

Comment: You should replace it with dsearchn instead of using a very old version. If you show us your failed tries in the form of an MCVE, we would  hopefully be able to resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*dsearch* was **removed** in MATLAB R2012a, therefore you may use any version of MATLAB before R2012a.

If you have an active MathWorks account, you may access the documentation archive [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to [MathWork's release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=dsearch&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), this function started printing a warning on release 2010a. So you should be fine either using it or a previous version.